# How to upload (pdf) file from FileReader to node js Express app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, fetch, filereader

I have a (React) js app that reads a PDF file using [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload) then uses [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to send it to a node js server running Express. When the request is received on the server side, however, the request body is **undefined**. What is missing from my code for this to work?

Client side:

```
function readFile() {
    let file = fileInputRef.current.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    return new Promise((resolve) => {         
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        resolve(e.target.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);//readAsDataURL, readAsArrayBuffer, or readAsBinaryString?
    });
  }

function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();    
readFile().then((value) => {
  fetch('/gen/file', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: value
  })
});
```

Server side:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express();
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
const port = 3000;

app.post("/gen/file",  function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);//undefined - Why????
});
app.listen(port, function (err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Client Side:

```
function getBase64(file,callback){
   const reader = new FileReader();
   reader.addEventListener('load',()=> callback(reader.result));
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    let body = {};
    getBase64(file,fileUrl=>{
      body.file = fileUrl;
      fetch('/gen/file', {
       method: 'POST',
       body
      })
    })
```

Server Side:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express();
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
const port = 3000;
const fs = require('fs');

app.post("/gen/file",  function (req, res, next) {
   console.log(req.body);//undefined - Why????
   let file =  req.body.file;
   let base64 =  file.match(/^data:([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/);
   var buffer = new Buffer.from(base64[2],'base64');
   fs.writeFile(__dirname+"/out.jpeg", buffer, 'base64', function (err) {
      console.log(err);
     });
 });
```